# how to call a text based token-string file in php

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner in `PHP` and have been working on a code which is of 2 parts

1. Logic PHP
2. GUI HTML/CSS

After processing the logic part I need to load the `HTML` part now my problem is that `HTML` contains lot of repetitive stuff i.e. the stuff which is going to be used again and again in the program so I don't want to keep writing the same thing again and again. I have seen somewhere we can call a text file which has all strings of data associated to a token and the same can be defined once and all then there is to do is all the token which is much more practical can someone help me in this for example my token string file:(Token and string are separated by <kbd>TAB</kbd>)

```
//Token          String
{NEWORDER0}      Thanks for your order
{NEWORDER1}      Your order will dispatch soon
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php) at the top of the scripts you need to use the [constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php)

**constants.php**

```
<?php
define('NEWORDER0', "Thanks for your order");
// etc..
```

then use it like this:

```
<?php
include_once("constants.php");
echo NEWORDER0;
```

Comment: ok but what if I wanted to call {NEWORDER0} outside php in a HTML code written after PHP

Comment: you should consider using a template engine, something like twig

Comment: ok I can try but my php and html are ready and I have never used twig it will cause more problems than solutions for me. Thanks I will still give a shot

Comment: You can run php code inside an html file, just add  `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm` to your `.htaccess`, this will make html files run as php

Comment: so this cannot be used like this:
<code>
<?php
define ('{NEWORDER}','Thanks for your order');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>{NEWORDER0}</title>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this , I have yet to try a working code of this

```
$file_handle = fopen("dictionary.txt", "rb");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
$line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
$parts = explode('=', $line_of_text);
print $parts[0] . $parts[1]. "<BR>";
}
fclose($file_handle);
```

source:[Reading text file into an array](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php10p7.html)